# Unable to read json object in Python function passed by javascript function--AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have been trying to send a json data strcuture to the python function (view.py). I am using Django framework. 
I have been successful in fetching the data from my textboxes and even store them. I can see that the relevant values get appended in the url too. 
But the problem arises when I try and read the value in my Python function which is corresponding to the next page.

```
function submit_this(url)
{
var i,j;var arr=[];
for(i=0; i<Hello.length; i++){
arr[i]=[];
for(j=0;j<Hello[i].length; j++)
{
arr[i].push(document.getElementById(Hello[i][j]).value);
}
} 
xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlHttpReq.open(\'POST\', url, true); xmlHttpReq.send(\'w=\' + encodeURI(arr));}
</script></head><body>
<form action=\"http://127.0.0.1:6000/params/button_click/\">
<center>
<button id="submit_button" name="submit_button"            onclick="submit_this(\'http://127.0.0.1:6000/params/button_click/\');"   value="Submit">Submit
</button>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried reading the values by using cgi. 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
but I get to know that the form is empty. 
I realise I am pretty close as the data structure (arr) has successfully been appended in the url for the next page. I am just unable to read it. 
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks. 
PS: Hello is also a Json object passed using a json file.

Comment: If this is Django, why are you using cgi.FieldStorage() rather than the Django request object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error: request.GET worked.